# Fragment inside a ScrollView is too small

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Short question: I want the fragment, which is inside a scroll view, to occupy all the available space. How can I achieve that?

Details: I have a fragment, which I put inside a ScrollView in the parent layout. That scroll view occupies most of the space in the parent layout. Despite that, the fragment appears very small inside the scroll view. The picture illustrates this:

[image: the fragment, or the scroll view, doesn't take the whole space]

This is the XML for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ImagePickerGridView" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp" android:background="@color/orange1">
</GridView>
```

This is the XML for the parent layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp">
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imagePickerScrollView" android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@color/orange1" android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue1">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="@string/ImportSelectedButton" android:id="@+id/importSelectedButton"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/standardMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standardMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standardMargin" android:onClick="onImportSelected"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="@string/CancelButton" android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/standardMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standardMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standardMargin" android:onClick="onCancel"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, this is how I add the fragment to the activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_picker_1);

    Log.d(CLASS_NAME, "onCreate");

    m_multiPicSelect = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(IntentHelper.MULTI_SELECT, false);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragment = new ImagePickerFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.imagePickerScrollView, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found out what was the problem. Turns out that `GridView` is a *scrollable* container, so there was no need to put it inside a `ScrollView`. Once I put the grid view inside a linear layout, everything worked! I still have no idea why the `GridView` shrank itself inside the `ScrollView`, maybe because shouldn't have been there in the first place :)

Thanks everybody for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

try this ::

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imagePickerScrollView" android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@color/orange1" android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical">
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work... However, I think I found the answer. I didn't realize that the GridView itself is a scrollable container! I'll post the solution in a minute. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

...as @nik said, but also add `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: thanks! as it turns out, the problem was putting the GridView inside the ScrollView. I explain this in a separate answer.